# Ubuntu hangs on start on system that have Windows 7

Tags: 12.10, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 using Live-USB stick on a system that have Windows 7 in [Asus 1025ce](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_1025CE), but after selecting Ubuntu in boot menu, system not started in first time and these messages appeared:

```
.

.

Starting: crash report submission daemon

Starting: regular background program processing daemon

Starting: deferred execution scheduler

Stopping

Starting: LightDM display manager

Starting: configure network device security

Starting: CPU interrupts balancing daemon

Starting: configure virtual network devices

Stopping: save kernel messages
```

and I waited for minutes, but system not starts. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @user68186 I edited Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Ubuntu 13.04 this problem will not exist!

Answer (score 0):

Boot into windows and delete everything in your usb flash drive.

THen download Unetbootin(no installation is required) and make a bootable usb in two clicks.

When it has finished its process it should tell you to reboot.

Install it and everything should be fine.

If this doesn't work leave a comment behind so I know.

Comment: I installed ubuntu using linux pen drive. is any difference between using linux pen drive or Unetbootin?

Comment: Unetbootin is a lot more friendly, you can get more support from it, it is quick and has a lot more options like instaliing the iso and burning to the usb all in one click. If you already have the iso then you can burn it with that instead.There is not any difference if you are doing t=anything in Ubuntu. Unetbootin should come in useful in the future as it can make many other Linux ditropution's iso without manually installing it.